# Rails 4: Log sql queries in a specific file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app. I have a main API stream and also a lib/service. So, to write logs in a file in the service I have:

```
class SpecificService  

  @logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log", APP_CONFIG['LOG_FILE'])) 
  @logger.info "MMKService.ENVIRONMENT=" + Rails.env.to_s
  if Rails.env.development?
    @logger.level = 0
  end
  if Rails.env.production?
    @logger.level = 1
  end
  if @logger.debug?
    @logger.info "MMKService-->Logger level = debug"
  else
    @logger.info "MMKService-->Logger level = info"
  end
```

This is writing logs to LOG_FILE in the service, while the main stream is writing logs in default log file development.log. The point is in development I want to show the sql query logs but they all sql queries goes to development.log, while I want the query logs generated in the services goes to LOG_FILE. Is it possible to split the sql logs to different places?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the logger for ActiveRecord at any time:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = @logger
```

With this, you should be able to toggle it on/off in your service.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand your point. If you config that I understand all sql logs will go to that file. But I need the sql logs generated in the service goes to a different file.